# Equivalent conditions for $\sigma(f)\subset\sigma(g)$

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Suppose  $f$ and $g$ are defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and are $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}^n)$-$\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ measurable.

Is it true that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f$ belong to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $g$ iff $g(x)=g(y)$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$?

---

I think this is true because I can’t find any counterexample. Could anyone help?

I found this on the book statistical inference by casella, in the chapter about minimal sufficient statistics. the original statement is: $f(x)=r(g(x))$ for some $r(x)$ from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$ iff $g(x)=g(y)$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$. But the book by casella doesn’t mention anything about measurability of $r(x)$, so I wonder if we can say that $r(x)$ is actually measurable.

Comment: Assume that $\sigma(f)=\sigma(g)=S$ and $g(x)=g(y)$. Then, for all $U\in S$, if $x\in S$ then $y\in S$. Now consider the set $U=f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})\in S$. We must have $y\in U$. Therefore $f(y)=f(x)$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod can you help prove the other direction? thx!